# pygame player shakes and flies after adding collision

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

The jumping part looks fine, but the player shakes while walking around and as I had different rects for walking and standing, when player walks into a wall it nicely stopped moving but as I stopped pressing moving button it would flash to the top of that wall, also while in the air, whenever player collide with tiles on x-axis it either flash to the top or bottom of that tile, I was expecting it to just slide on the wall.

Here's my code for player

```
class Player():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.img_stand = pygame.image.load('D:\ThingThing\inthething\H stand.png')
        self.img_standL = pygame.image.load('D:\ThingThing\inthething\H standL.png')
        #walk animation
        self.images_right = []
        self.images_left = []
        self.index = 0
        self.counter = 0
        self.direction = 0


        for num in range(1,17):
            img_right = pygame.image.load(f'D:\ThingThing\inthething\H walk{num}.png')
            self.images_right.append(img_right)

        for num in range(1,17):
            img_left = pygame.image.load(f'D:\ThingThing\inthething\H walkL{num}.png')
            self.images_left.append(img_left)

        self.image = self.img_stand
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        print(self.rect)

        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.width = self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.image.get_height()

        self.vel_y = 0
        self.jumped = False
    def update(self):
        dx = 0
        dy = 0
        walk_cooldown = 8



        #get key
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            dx -= 1
            self.counter += 1
            self.image = self.images_left[self.index]
            self.tempx = self.rect.centerx
            self.tempy = self.rect.bottom
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.centerx = self.tempx
            self.rect.bottom = self.tempy


            self.direction = -1
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            dx += 1
            self.counter += 1
            self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
            self.direction = 1
            self.tempx = self.rect.centerx
            self.tempy = self.rect.bottom
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.centerx = self.tempx
            self.rect.bottom = self.tempy

        if key[pygame.K_SPACE] and self.jumped == False:
            self.vel_y = -8
            self.jumped = True


        if key[pygame.K_SPACE] == False:
            self.jumped = False
        if (key[pygame.K_LEFT] == False and key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == False) or (key[pygame.K_LEFT] == True and key[pygame.K_RIGHT] == True):
            self.counter = 0
            self.index = 0
            if self.direction == 1:
                self.image = self.img_stand

            if self.direction == -1:
                self.image = self.img_standL
            self.tempx = self.rect.centerx
            self.tempy = self.rect.bottom
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.centerx = self.tempx
            self.rect.bottom = self.tempy



        if self.counter > walk_cooldown:
            self.counter = 0
            self.index += 1
            if self.direction == 1:
                if self.index >= len(self.images_right):
                    self.index = 0
                self.image = self.images_right[self.index]
            if self.direction == -1:
                if self.index >= len(self.images_left):
                    self.index = 0
                self.image = self.images_left[self.index]



        #jump + gravity
        self.vel_y += 0.3
        if self.vel_y > 10:
            self.vel_y = 10
        dy += self.vel_y

        #collision
        for tile in world.tile_list:
            #x
            if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x + dx, self.rect.y, self.width, self.height) and dx > 0:
                dx = 0



            #y
            if tile[1].colliderect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + dy, self.width, self.height):
                #check if below the ground
                if self.vel_y < 0:
                    dy = tile[1].bottom - self.rect.top
                    self.vel_y = 0
                elif self.vel_y > 0:
                    dy = tile[1].top - self.rect.bottom
                    self.vel_y = 0



        #move

        self.rect.centerx += dx
        self.rect.bottom += dy





        if self.rect.bottom > 540:
            self.rect.bottom = 540
            dy = 0






        #onto screen
        screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,255,255),self.rect,2)
```

I think the problem is about different rects. Should I just use the same rect for walking and standing?

Answer (score 1):

> whenever player collide with tiles on x-axis it either flash to the top or bottom of that tile [...]

This problem is obvious. When moving the player near an obstacle, the collision detection prevents the player from overlapping the obstacle, but positioned to touch the obstacle.
However, when you stop moving, the player's image changes and the player's bounding box may change in size. Now the player and the obstacle suddenly collide and the collision detection algorithm places the player at the top or bottom of the obstacle.
I suggest using a constant size hitbox for collision detection, or at least a larger hitbox when the player walks so that they come to a stop far enough away from the obstacle.